# Python: Variance of a list of defined numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, variance, defined

I am trying to make a function that prints the variance of a list of defined numbers:

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]
```

So far, I have tried proceeding on making these three functions:

```
def grades_sum(my_list):
    total = 0
    for grade in my_list: 
        total += grade
    return total

def grades_average(my_list):
    sum_of_grades = grades_sum(my_list)
    average = sum_of_grades / len(my_list)
    return average

def grades_variance(my_list, average):
    variance = 0
    for i in my_list:
        variance += (average - my_list[i]) ** 2
    return variance / len(my_list)
```

When I try to execute the code, however, it gives me the following error at the following line:

```
Line: variance += (average - my_list[i]) ** 2
Error: list index out of range
```

Apologies if my current Python knowledges are limited, but I am still learning - so please if you wish to help solving this issue try not to suggest extremely-complicated ways on how to solve this, thank you really much.

Comment: Just as a note, [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in function that already exists - no  need to reinvent the wheel. `sum(grades)` will do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I would suggest using Python's built-in `sum` method to replace your first custom method. `grades_average` then becomes:

```
def grades_average(my_list):
    sum_of_grades = sum(my_list)
    average = sum_of_grades / len(my_list)
    return average
```

Second, I would strongly recommend looking into the [NumPy library](https://numpy.org), as it has these methods built-in. `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.std()` would cover both these cases.

If you're interested in writing the code for yourself first, that's totally fine too. As for your specific error, I believe @gnibbler above nailed it. If you want to loop using an index, you can restructure the line in `grades_variance` to be:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
```

As [Lattyware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722121/gareth-latty) noted, looping by index is not particularly "Pythonic"; the way you're currently doing it is generally superior. This is just for your reference.

Comment: It's worth noting looping by index is a terrible idea in Python - it's harder to read, slower and makes your code inflexible.

Comment: Agreed, but it's useful to know how to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "the way I am currently doing it is generally superior"?

Comment: Your current loop construction makes `i` the item in the list. I gave the loop structure for making `i` an integer index into the list. The former (how you do it in your original question) is generally better.

Comment: As of Python 3.4, there are [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) and [`variance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance) functions in the [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics). No need to load NumPy just to calculate a variance anymore.

Answer (score 23):

Try [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy.var).

```
import numpy as np
variance = np.var(grades)
```

Answer (score 6):

When you say

```
 for i in my_list:
```

`i` isn't the *index* of the item. `i` *is* the item

```
for i in my_list:
    variance += (average - i) ** 2
```

Answer (score 5):

While [gnibbler has solved the problem with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16670690/722121), you can achieve this much more easily using [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
varience = sum((average - value) ** 2 for value in grades) / len(grades)
```

It might look a little scary at first, but if you watch the video I link about list comprehensions and generator expressions - they are actually really simple and useful.

Comment: Note that you want 2.0 if you're on python 2.x

Answer (score 5):

python 3.4 has a statistics lib which does this.

```
   import statistics
   grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]
   statistics.pvariance(grades)
=> 334.07100591715977
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.pvariance

Comment: I would just love to see a `statistics` port to python 2.7

Comment: Wow, congrats!! ;D Really thanks, that will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The below code is used to get the variance I create a custom function

```
   def variance(val):
       total_sum=sum(val)
       average=total_sum/len(val)
       a=[]
       for i in val:
           a.append((i-average)**2)
       return sum(a)/len(a)

   val=[2.18,2.22,2.24,1.62,1.32,1.85,1.85,2.70,3.60,4.60,1.38,2.34,2.71]
   variance(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would like the sample variance i.e. the unbiased estimator of the variance. I think this function might do the job. It will print the variance and the mean of a vector n.

```
n = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

def variance1337(n):
    var1 = []
    mean1 = sum(n)/len(n)
    for xs in n:
        var1.append((xs - mean1) ** 2)
    print(sum(var1)/(len(n) - 1))
    print(mean1)
```

Answer (score -1):

the below code is used to get the average of values

```
def grades_average(my_list):
    sum_of_grades = sum(my_list)
    average = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)
    return average
```

variance formula -> The average of the squared differences from the Mean.
This code below is used to get the variance of values

```
def grades_variance(my_list, average):
    variance = 0
    for i in my_list:
         variance += (average - i) ** 2
    return variance / len(my_list)
```